# slapd doesn't start automatically despite rc.conf entry

Tags: freebsd, openldap, rc

I can successfully start `slapd` on FreeBSD 11 perfectly fine, but it won't run on startup. Here is what I put in my `rc.conf`:

```
slapd_enable="YES"
slapd_flags="-h "ldap://1.2.3.4/ ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fopenldap%2fldapi/""
slapd_sockets="/var/run/openldap/ldapi"
```

`1.2.3.4` is replaced with my actual public IP.

I have tried many permutations of the valid options for `slapd_flags` and `slapd_sockets`, but every time I reboot `slapd` is not running.

How do I ensure `slapd` runs at system startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't post this until I had searched for days, and I just now found the answer. If no one else finds this useful, I'll end up deleting, but here it is:

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/58365/

Basically, if networking isn't up yet, then it cannot bind and will fail. The solution is to edit `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/slapd` and change this line:

```
# REQUIRE: FILESYSTEMS ldconfig
```

To:

```
# REQUIRE: FILESYSTEMS ldconfig NETWORKING
```

This ensures networking is loaded prior to attempting to start `slapd`.